# Are there automated translator from one programming language to another?

Tags: machine-learning, automation, build-automation

As most of the programming languages are Turing complete, a program written in one programming language can be solved in another programming language. Why there are not automated translator tools that convert the program written in one language (ex. C++) to other programming languages (ex. Java)?

Comment: That's a very ill-conditioned problem (no unique solution) and probably will get NP-hard when using additional constraints (and might be even for the unconstrained case). And that's only a theoretical view ignoring differences like garbage-collection vs. no garbage-collection (which might limit a behaviourA -> behaviourB translation opposed to resultA -> resultB).

Comment: We call them "compilers", e.g. a Kaffee task can be solved in Javascript, or a C++ task in x86.

Answer (score 1):

While there have been some solutions for this task, in commercial as well as in open source, those solutions were far form perfect. It seems like now a game changer is in town with facebook's new [Transcoder](https://ai.facebook.com/blog/deep-learning-to-translate-between-programming-languages/), an AI solution that offers more than 90% accuracy in Java to C++ translations. It translates to and from Python, too, and is [avaliable in github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TransCoder) to be trained for other languages.